# How to project nested documents along side properties in the root document?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I am attempting to return a projection of a nested document and some properties from the root document also. I would like to do this within the query if at all possible.

For example, I have an index `cities` where and the initial dataset:

```json
[
    {
        _id: "1",
        city: "New York"
        state:"NY"
        users: [ 
         {
            firstName: "John",
            lastname: "Peters",
            birthYear: 1985
         }, {
            firstName: "Raul",
            lastname: "Other",
            birthYear: 1986
         }, {
            firstName: "Paul",
            lastname: "Ray",
            birthYear: 1997
         }
        ]       
    },
    {
        _id: "2",
        city: "Hackensack",
        state: "NJ"
        users: [ 
         {
            firstName: "Joe",
            lastname: "Anders",
            birthYear: 1988
         }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        _id: "3",
        city: "Albany"
        state:"NY"
        users: [ 
         {
            firstName: "Zoy",
            lastname: "Bat",
            birthYear: 1984
         }, {
            firstName: "Ana",
            lastname: "Lily",
            birthYear: 1999
         }
        ]        
    }
]
```

`users` is of type `nested`. (S/n: I think this is for the best currently because I would like to possibly filter on one of the properties, but I am willing to change this if need be.)

I would like to do a query for users in the `state` of `NY` ordered by `birthYear`, and what I would like Elasticsearch to return is something like:

```json
[
  {
    city: "Albany"
    firstName: "Zoy",
    lastname: "Bat",
    birthYear: 1984
  }, {
    city: "New York"
    firstName: "John",
    lastname: "Peters",
    birthYear: 1985
  }, { 
    city: "New York"
    firstName: "Raul",
    lastname: "Other",
    birthYear: 1986
  }, {
    city: "New York"
    firstName: "Paul",
    lastname: "Ray",
    birthYear: 1997
  }, {
    city: "Albany"
    firstName: "Ana",
    lastname: "Lily",
    birthYear: 1999
  }        
]
```

This feels like something that should be possible during query time but I have not been able to find the appropriate functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to return what you expect using nested documents, as you cannot mix and match documents nested into different top-level documents and return them in the order you mention.

You should actually **denormalize your data** and **promote users to primary entities**. First, that would easily solve the query need you expressed and second I'm pretty confident this would also support your other needs.

So your documents should look like this instead:

```
 {
    id": 1,
    firstName: "John",
    lastname: "Peters",
    birthYear: 1985,
    city: "New York",
    state:"NY"
 }
 {
    id": 2,
    firstName: "Raul",
    lastname: "Other",
    birthYear: 1986,
    city: "New York",
    state:"NY"
 }
 etc...
```

Comment: Hello, I have been looking more into this and found [reverse nested aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-reverse-nested-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-reverse-nested-aggregation). This seem like it may possibly be what I was looking for looking into it further.

Comment: The reverse aggregation seems to allow you to aggregate on parent docs from nested documents. This is not exactly what I was looking for but the concept is there.

Comment: I tend to agree that denormalizing feels like the correct solution for this but I was just hoping to find a built in way to accomplish what I wanted. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Reverse nested aggregation will not allow you to sort documents as you wish. Aggregations and documents are two orthogonal concepts. Nested documents will always stay in the context of their parent document, you will never be able to mix and match them into another cross-document sorted list

Comment: No nothing else is needed thank you for your help.