# Sort by a value from a nested array in ElasticSearch and interlace results

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index where each document has a nested field with 0 or more nested documents. I need to be able to sort on the values of those nested documents, but I want my results to be sorted **at the level of the nested document**. So for example if I have these 2 documents:

```
{"_id":1,"name":"dogs","menu":[{"item_name":"hot dog","price":5}]},
{"_id":2,"name":"bar","menu":[{"item_name":"beer","price":10},{"item_name":"soda","price":2}]}
```

and I sort by menu.price desc, I need to get a result like this:

```
{"_id":2,"name":"bar","menu":[{"item_name":"beer","price":10}]},
{"_id":1,"name":"dogs","menu":[{"item_name":"hot dog","price":5}]},
{"_id":2,"name":"bar","menu":[{"item_name":"soda","price":2}]}
```

but if I just sort by menu.price desc I get this:

```
{"_id":2,"name":"bar","menu":[{"item_name":"beer","price":10},{"item_name":"soda","price":2}]},
{"_id":1,"name":"dogs","menu":[{"item_name":"hot dog","price":5}]}
```

Is there a way to get this intended behavior in Elastic? I have a large dataset that needs to be properly paginated so there isn't much I can do after query time. A new index with the nested field at the top-level is not a scalable solution for me since there will be many nested fields added over time.

I am currently using ElasticSearch 7.12.1

Comment: Same question as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68535666/4604579 . It is not possible to "unwrap" nested documents and sort them independently as if they were standalone documents.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the example, I assume you want to return the top-level documents; but want to sort at the nested level. That's supported in elasticsearch; Please refer to [this part](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/sort-search-results.html#nested-sorting) of documentation

But if you want to 'unwrap' and sort nested documents along with non-nested documents, that's not supported ( As one of the comment suggests). I suggest reading the above documentation first to see if it fits your needs ( looks like it might)

Note regarding nested documents and scalability. If the index is huge - nested documents will consume more resources and will impact performance.

Some of the factors ...

1 - Every nested document is indexed as a separate document internally and joined in query time using ( block-join query); So that increases the number of documents

2 - Indexing time heap usage might be high if you have many documents with tens of thousands of nested entities

3  - Nested documents consume heap to cache some data structures, so you might end up with more heap usage.

So if there is a way to avoid nested - absolutely do it! - but there are scenarios where they make sense!